# prevent rendering of <li> tag or any other HTML tags

Tags: html, web, rendering, web-deployment

I want the browser to print < li > or any other tag as it is, not to render it as a tag. Is that possible in HTML? I found a way to hack it that is to add spaces between < and 'li'. But this does not seem to be professional. Is there another way?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hi @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, <pre> tag is not working now. Can you test that please.

Comment: You can use the `xmp` tag as suggested in that answer (although it is recommended to use `pre`). If you use `pre` you'll need to escape the `<` and `>`. That question also has an answer that suggests using a textarea if you want

Comment: Okay, thanks. This question, in fact, is a duplicate of that one.